# Replacing the position of an element in Array of Array

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I have been trying to run this loop to change the position of an element in an array based but I get the error below. Not really sure what could be wrong. Any thoughts or Ideas!! Thanks.

[image]

```
var population = [[98, 8, 45, 34, 56], [9, 13, 65, 4, 90], [24, 5, 4, 56, 88], [3, 55, 22, 19, 10]]

private func randomIntergerInRange(low:Int, high:Int) -> Int {
    let randomGeneratedNumber = low + Int(arc4random()) % (high - low);
    return Int(randomGeneratedNumber)
}

for individual in population {
    var mutate = 0.01

    if mutate > Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) {

        var positionToMutate = randomIntergerInRange(0, (individual.count - 1))

        var valueToAssign = randomIntergerInRange(minElement(individual), maxElement(individual))

        individual[positionToMutate] = valueToAssign
        print(individual)

    }
}
```

Comment: why your array look more like an Dictionary

Comment: It's an array of Arrays @Lamar ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for the error message: the `individual` object in your loop is immutable, it's a copy of the object, not a reference.

You could do something like this, using `enumerate`:

```
for (index, individual) in enumerate(population) {
    var mutate = 0.01

    if mutate > Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) {

        var positionToMutate = randomIntergerInRange(0, (individual.count - 1))

        var valueToAssign = randomIntergerInRange(minElement(individual), maxElement(individual))

        population[index][positionToMutate] = valueToAssign

        print(population[index])

    }
}
```

You shouldn't modify a collection while iterating it, btw, it could have side effects.

**Update for Swift 2**

```
private func randomIntegerInRange(low:Int, _ high:Int) -> Int {
    let randomGeneratedNumber = low + Int(arc4random()) % (high - low)
    return Int(randomGeneratedNumber)
}

var mutate = 0.01
for (index, individual) in population.enumerate() {
    if mutate > Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) {
        var positionToMutate = randomIntegerInRange(0, (individual.count - 1))
        if let min = individual.minElement(), max = individual.maxElement() {
            var valueToAssign = randomIntegerInRange(min, max)
            population[index][positionToMutate] = valueToAssign
            print(population[index])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. ;). Stuff I wasn't really sure of!.

Answer (score 2):

Array are passed by value, so when you use `individual` at each iteration it is assigned a copy of the subarray of `population`, and even if you use `for var individual in population ...` you mutate only a copy of the original array.

If you want to mutate the values of the original array you can do it by using indices, for instance:

```
for index in population.indices {
    var mutate = 0.01

    if mutate > Double(Float(arc4random()) / Float(UINT32_MAX)) {

        var positionToMutate = randomIntergerInRange(0, (population[index].count - 1))

        var valueToAssign = randomIntergerInRange(minElement(population[index]), maxElement(population[index]))

        population[index][positionToMutate] = valueToAssign
        print(population[index])

    }
}
```

Comment: Oh I see. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks a lot. ;) @Renzo